# Yaml to jinja2 dict structure is breaking while templating

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

Here is my problem. I have a set of firewall rules I need to template in ansible. The rules are part of an inventory item, and some elements are lists. I can get the elements to print properly until I add the list. What is the correct jinja2 expression to get this yaml data to loop properly?

Here is my dataset:

```
# inventory item details:
    lighthouse2:
      ansible_host: 
      nebula_ip: 10.222.222.253
      nebula_domain: skynet
      groups: lighthouse
      firewall:
        web443:
          port: 443
          protocol: any
          host: any
          groups:
            - admin
            - lighthouse
        web80:
          port: 80
          protocol: any
          host: any
```

Here is what I currently have for my jinja2 template that works without the groups:

```
{% if firewall is defined %}
    # Begin rules from ansible inventory
    {% for rulename, ruledata in firewall.items() -%}
    #Allow {{ rulename }}
    - port: {{ ruledata.port }}
      protocol: {{ ruledata.protocol }}
      host: {{ ruledata.host }}
    {% endfor %}
# End rules from ansible inventory
{% endif %}
```

The jinja output is perfect:

```
    # Begin rules from ansible inventory
    #Allow web443
    - port: 443
      protocol: any
      host: any
    #Allow web80
    - port: 80
      protocol: any
      host: any
    # End rules from ansible inventory
```

But I need to get the `groups` list in there. So I try adding another line for groups by adding a line groups, here is the jinja2 template with the additional line:

```
{% if firewall is defined %}
    # Begin rules from ansible inventory
    {% for rulename, ruledata in firewall.items() -%}
    #Allow {{ rulename }}
    - port: {{ ruledata.port }}
      protocol: {{ ruledata.protocol }}
      host: {{ ruledata.host }}
      groups: {{ ruledata.groups }}
    {% endfor %}
# End rules from ansible inventory
{% endif %}
```

And the resulting output from ansible is:

```
TASK [create some file] ******************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'groups'
fatal: [lighthouse2 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'groups'"}
```

What am I doing wrong to not be able to traverse my way down this data?

Comment: Hi J P welcome to SO. Never use a text formatting language to generate structured data like json or yaml; that's what [`|to_yaml`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) is for. Anyway, it seems like your example and your code are not matching up. Try just dumping the variable in order to have a look at it `{{ ruledata | to_json }}` or such. Good luck

Comment: also, note that in the example `lighthouse2`, `groups` is at the same level as `firewall`, that is why you are receiving the error `has no attribute 'groups'` when using `ruledata.groups` which assumes group is a child of firewall

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas, `groups` is a key of the device and a key of the firewall. Thanks for pointing that out, I will make them more clear.

Comment: @mdaniel I was working with that but to_yaml seems to parse and reorganize the keys. It's probably a mistake on my part though... I am doing a little bit of translation there for the two different structures.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Either test the existence of the attribute

```yaml
    {% if firewall is defined %}
    # Begin rules from ansible inventory
    {% for rulename, ruledata in firewall.items() -%}
    #Allow {{ rulename }}
    - port: {{ ruledata.port }}
      protocol: {{ ruledata.protocol }}
      host: {{ ruledata.host }}
    {% if ruledata.groups is defined %}
      groups: {{ ruledata.groups }}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    # End rules from ansible inventory
    {% endif %}
```

gives

```yaml
    # Begin rules from ansible inventory
    #Allow web443
    - port: 443
      protocol: any
      host: any
      groups: ['admin', 'lighthouse']
    #Allow web80
    - port: 80
      protocol: any
      host: any
    # End rules from ansible inventory
```

2. Or use a default value

```yaml
    {% if firewall is defined %}
    # Begin rules from ansible inventory
    {% for rulename, ruledata in firewall.items() -%}
    #Allow {{ rulename }}
    - port: {{ ruledata.port }}
      protocol: {{ ruledata.protocol }}
      host: {{ ruledata.host }}
      groups: {{ ruledata.groups|default([]) }}
    {% endfor %}
    # End rules from ansible inventory
    {% endif %}
```

gives

```yaml
    # Begin rules from ansible inventory
    #Allow web443
    - port: 443
      protocol: any
      host: any
      groups: ['admin', 'lighthouse']
    #Allow web80
    - port: 80
      protocol: any
      host: any
      groups: []
    # End rules from ansible inventory
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    firewall:
      web443:
        port: 443
        protocol: any
        host: any
        groups:
          - admin
          - lighthouse
      web80:
        port: 80
        protocol: any
        host: any

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% if firewall is defined %}
          # Begin rules from ansible inventory
          {% for rulename, ruledata in firewall.items() -%}
          #Allow {{ rulename }}
          - port: {{ ruledata.port }}
            protocol: {{ ruledata.protocol }}
            host: {{ ruledata.host }}
            groups: {{ ruledata.groups|default([]) }}
          {% endfor %}
          # End rules from ansible inventory
          {% endif %}

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% if firewall is defined %}
          # Begin rules from ansible inventory
          {% for rulename, ruledata in firewall.items() -%}
          #Allow {{ rulename }}
          - port: {{ ruledata.port }}
            protocol: {{ ruledata.protocol }}
            host: {{ ruledata.host }}
          {% if ruledata.groups is defined %}
            groups: {{ ruledata.groups }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          # End rules from ansible inventory
          {% endif %}
```